# Installing php and nodejs on ubuntu 17

Tags: ubuntu, npm

I'm trying to install node js with ubuntu 17. I keep getting this error. I have no idea what it means.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
```

.

```
 Repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from '***** The main PPA for PHP (5.6, 7.0, 7.1) with many PECL extensions *****' to '***** The main PPA for supported PHP versions with many PECL extensions *****'
    N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say, **I don't know these features of Ubuntu very well**, so the described solution may cause damage to your system.

According to the [apt-secure manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/apt/apt-secure.8.en.html), this is a security feature to prevent installation of compromised or potentially harmful packages.

I had the same issue and ran `sudo apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change` a few times until I got rid of the error.

After that I used

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
```

and finally

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

to update my node installation.